# How to download multiple strings from the internet and check if one is true

Tags: c#

Im Trying to grab a boat load of usernames and passwords off a pastbin  file and its only allowing me to grab one. Any suggestions

NOTE: i would like it to read this format  User:Pass (ENTER) Hello:Bye Ect. >>> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LAUx2zxn

```C#
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //userinfo - text file should look like:    UsernameHere:PasswordHere
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string userinfo = client.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LAUx2zxn");

            if (userinfo == username.Text + ":" + password.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in as " + username.Text + ".", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                label1.Text = "Welcome, " + username.Text;
                label1.Visible = true;
                this.Hide();
                MainMenu ss = new MainMenu();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // Login failed, I added my own stuff here.
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid account info entered.\n If you want to buy an account msg\n YouRGenetics \nOn Skype\n Or Click On Buy Account", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Comment: You are downloading all the usernames and passwords into a single userinfo string. You have to split the string into an array of strings and loop through the array and check if each string satisfies your criteria.

Comment: You should remember that `WebClient` is disposable. You must call `.Dispose()` on it after you have finished with the object otherwise it is a memory leak. It's best to use a `using` statement to enforce the disposing for you.

Comment: You're not actually doing this as a method to authenticate users are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this isn't a great way to authenticate users. But assuming you're just doing this to learn:

WebClient.DownLoadString() is getting the content of the page as one whole string. You will have to split the string. Something like this will work for your conditional:

```
        bool authenticated = false;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string userinfoLines = client.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LAUx2zxn");
        foreach (string userinfo in userinfoLines.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
        if (userinfo == username.Text + ":" + password.Text)
        {
            authenticated = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in as " + username.Text + ".", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            label1.Text = "Welcome, " + username.Text;
            label1.Visible = true;
            this.Hide();
            MainMenu ss = new MainMenu();
            ss.Show();
            break;
        }
        }
        if (!authenticated)
        {
            // Login failed, I added my own stuff here.
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid account info entered.\n If you want to buy an account msg\n YouRGenetics \nOn Skype\n Or Click On Buy Account", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: You are correct i am doing this to learn. Do you mind teaching me abit on skype if you have time?

Comment: I might not be much help on Skype. You're better off asking questions here where there are a lot of good people to answer your questions :). Also follow Enigmativity's advice on Disposing WebClient by .Dispose() or using `using` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var client = new WebClient();
var source = client.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LAUx2zxn");
var data = new List<string>(source.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

if (data.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower()).Contains(string.Concat("user", ":", "pass")))
{
     // Successfully logged in.
}
else
{
     // Invalid credentials
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, Yours worked as-well but i chose his b/c i understood it better. (: If i could give two checks i would. Thanks <3